# Local rails application on Mac starts fine but always shuts down when functions used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, osx-lion, pow

I have a problem with running a rails application locally on my Mac (10.7.1) for over a week now.
The app is starting fine but always shutting down the server once I start using some functions. The strange thing is that this doesn't happen all the time, sometimes it runs smoothly for days and on my friends Windows it works perfectly all the time.

I use rvm (1.7.2) and tried with ruby 1.9.2 and also 1.8.7 as well as Rails 3.0.9 and 3.1rc6.

1. I tried with **Pow** (0.3.1 and 0.3.2) with the following error:

   ```
   Error: Response was not received  
   Error: Response was not received  
       at Client._finishRequest (/Users/philipp/Library/Application   Support/Pow/Versions/0.3.2/node_modules/nack/lib/client.js:75:27)  
       at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/philipp/Library/Application   Support/Pow/Versions/0.3.2/node_modules/nack/lib/client.js:37:21)  
       at Client.emit (events.js:81:20)  
       at Array.0 (net.js:831:12)  
       at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
   ```
2. Also with the **builtin rails server command**:

   ```
   DEPRECATION WARNING: config.action_view.debug_rjs will be removed in 3.1, from 3.1 onwards you will need to install prototype-rails to continue to use RJS templates . (called from service at /Users/philipp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111)
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:288: [BUG] Segmentation fault  
   ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.0.0]  
   -- control frame ----------  
   c:0084 p:---- s:0431 b:0431 l:000430 d:000430 CFUNC  :module_eval  
   c:0083 p:0144 s:0425 b:0425 l:000406 d:000424 BLOCK  /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-  p290/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:288  
   c:0082 p:---- s:0420 b:0420 l:000419 d:000419 FINISH  
   c:0081 p:---- s:0418 b:0418 l:000417 d:000417 CFUNC  :each  
   c:0080 p:0015 s:0415 b:0415 l:000406 d:000414 BLOCK  /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-  p290/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:279  
   c:0079 p:---- s:0412 b:0412 l:000411 d:000411 FINISH  
   c:0078 p:---- s:0410 b:0410 l:000409 d:000409 CFUNC  :each  
   c:0077 p:0029 s:0407 b:0407 l:000406 d:000406 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-  p290/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:278  
   c:0076 p:0023 s:0403 b:0403 l:000402 d:000402 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-  p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:13  
   c:0075 p:0032 s:0400 b:0400 l:000399 d:000399 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-  p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:51  
   c:0074 p:0055 s:0396 b:0396 l:000386 d:000395 BLOCK  /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-  p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1564  
   c:0073 p:---- s:0392 b:0392 l:000391 d:000391 FINISH  
   c:0072 p:---- s:0390 b:0390 l:000389 d:000389 CFUNC  :each  
   c:0071 p:0076 s:0387 b:0387 l:000386 d:000386 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-   p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1560  
   c:0070 p:0107 s:0380 b:0380 l:000379 d:000379 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-  p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1412  
   c:0069 p:---- s:0375 b:0375 l:000374 d:000374 FINISH  
   c:0068 p:---- s:0373 b:0373 l:000372 d:000372 CFUNC  :new  
   c:0067 p:0049 s:0369 b:0369 l:000368 d:000368 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-  p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:502  
   c:0066 p:0373 s:0363 b:0363 l:000362 d:000362 METHOD   /Users/philipp/Desktop/Projects/Prototyp/Bora/app/controllers/products_controller.rb:48  
   c:0065 p:0012 s:0358 b:0358 l:000357 d:000357 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-  p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4  
   c:0064 p:0015 s:0353 b:0353 l:000352 d:000352 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150
   c:0063 p:0041 s:0348 b:0348 l:000347 d:000347 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11
   c:0062 p:0012 s:0344 b:0344 l:000568 d:000343 BLOCK  /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18
   c:0061 p:0063 s:0342 b:0342 l:000341 d:000341 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436
   c:0060 p:0113 s:0336 b:0336 l:000335 d:000335 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410
   c:0059 p:0024 s:0327 b:0327 l:000326 d:000326 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94
   c:0058 p:0020 s:0321 b:0321 l:000568 d:000568 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17
   c:0057 p:0012 s:0316 b:0316 l:000297 d:000315 BLOCK  /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30
   c:0056 p:0017 s:0312 b:0312 l:000302 d:000311 BLOCK  /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52
   c:0055 p:0032 s:0310 b:0310 l:000309 d:000309 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21
   c:0054 p:0036 s:0303 b:0303 l:000302 d:000302 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52
   c:0053 p:0152 s:0298 b:0298 l:000297 d:000297 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29
   c:0052 p:0012 s:0292 b:0292 l:000291 d:000291 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17
   c:0051 p:0093 s:0287 b:0287 l:000286 d:000286 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119
   c:0050 p:0084 s:0281 b:0281 l:000280 d:000280 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41
   c:0049 p:0048 s:0276 b:0276 l:000275 d:000275 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138
   c:0048 p:0086 s:0271 b:0271 l:000270 d:000270 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14
   c:0047 p:0030 s:0265 b:0265 l:000778 d:000264 BLOCK  /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178
   c:0046 p:---- s:0262 b:0262 l:000261 d:000261 FINISH
   c:0045 p:---- s:0260 b:0260 l:000259 d:000259 CFUNC  :call
   c:0044 p:0022 s:0256 b:0256 l:000255 d:000255 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62
   c:0043 p:0094 s:0250 b:0250 l:000249 d:000249 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27
   c:0042 p:0097 s:0244 b:0244 l:000216 d:000243 BLOCK  /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148
   c:0041 p:0014 s:0238 b:0238 l:000222 d:000237 BLOCK  /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93
   c:0040 p:0518 s:0233 b:0233 l:000232 d:000232 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:82
   c:0039 p:0137 s:0223 b:0223 l:000222 d:000222 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92
   c:0038 p:0092 s:0217 b:0217 l:000216 d:000216 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139
   c:0037 p:0025 s:0211 b:0211 l:000210 d:000210 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493
   c:0036 p:0015 s:0207 b:0207 l:000206 d:000206 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17
   c:0035 p:0093 s:0200 b:0200 l:000199 d:000199 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14
   c:0034 p:0155 s:0193 b:0193 l:000192 d:000192 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24
   c:0033 p:0046 s:0187 b:0187 l:000186 d:000186 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21
   c:0032 p:0054 s:0182 b:0182 l:000181 d:000181 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182
   c:0031 p:0027 s:0175 b:0175 l:000174 d:000174 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149
   c:0030 p:0015 s:0164 b:0164 l:000163 d:000163 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302
   c:0029 p:0014 s:0156 b:0156 l:001ed0 d:000155 BLOCK  /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32
   c:0028 p:0019 s:0154 b:0154 l:000153 d:000153 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:
   c:0027 p:0051 s:0150 b:0150 l:000149 d:000149 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12
   c:0026 p:0019 s:0146 b:0146 l:001ed0 d:001ed0 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31
   c:0025 p:0015 s:0142 b:0142 l:000141 d:000141 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool
   c:0024 p:0029 s:0138 b:0138 l:000ba0 d:000137 BLOCK  /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46
   c:0023 p:0155 s:0136 b:0136 l:000135 d:000135 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416
   c:0022 p:0011 s:0126 b:0126 l:000ba0 d:000ba0 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44
   c:0021 p:0015 s:0122 b:0122 l:000121 d:000121 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107
   c:0020 p:0049 s:0112 b:0112 l:000111 d:000111 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48
   c:0019 p:0017 s:0108 b:0108 l:000107 d:000107 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47
   c:0018 p:0027 s:0100 b:0100 l:000099 d:000099 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13
   c:0017 p:0032 s:0096 b:0096 l:000095 d:000095 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17
   c:0016 p:0052 s:0087 b:0087 l:000086 d:000086 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72
   c:0015 p:0014 s:0083 b:0083 l:000077 d:000082 BLOCK  /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11
   c:0014 p:0019 s:0081 b:0081 l:000080 d:000080 METHOD <internal:prelude>:10
   c:0013 p:0054 s:0078 b:0078 l:000077 d:000077 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11
   c:0012 p:0193 s:0073 b:0073 l:000072 d:000072 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30
   c:0011 p:0032 s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:168
   c:0010 p:0021 s:0062 b:0062 l:000061 d:000061 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77
   c:0009 p:---- s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 FINISH
   c:0008 p:0015 s:0055 b:0055 l:000054 d:000054 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14
   c:0007 p:0015 s:0050 b:0050 l:000049 d:000049 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13
   c:0006 p:0338 s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52
   c:0005 p:0257 s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111
   c:0004 p:0393 s:0020 b:0020 l:000019 d:000019 METHOD /Users/philipp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70
   c:0003 p:0126 s:0009 b:0009 l:0022a8 d:000008 BLOCK  /Users/philipp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183
   c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
   c:0001 p:---- s:0002 b:0002 l:000001 d:000001 TOP   
   >---------------------------
   >-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
   <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:82:in `optimized_each'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-mount-0.6.14/lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__3376809915562667250__process_action__212256881250680574__callbacks'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
   /Users/philipp/Desktop/Projects/Prototyp/Bora/app/controllers/products_controller.rb:48:in `new'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:502:in `create'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:502:in `new'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1412:in `initialize'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1560:in `attributes='
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1560:in `each'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:1564:in `block in attributes='
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:51:in `respond_to?'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:13:in `define_attribute_methods'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:278:in `define_attribute_methods'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:278:in `each'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:279:in `block in define_attribute_methods'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:279:in `each'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:288:in `block (2 levels) in define_attribute_methods'
   /Users/philipp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:288:in `module_eval'
   -- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
   [NOTE]
   You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
   Bug reports are welcome.
   For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
   Abort trap: 6
   ```
3. **Nginx** (with passenger) error is: 502 Bad Gateway

There seems to be an issue related to this on [githubs issue list](https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/149) but sadly no solution as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Nokogiri-Gem was messing up things and had to be uninstalled and compiled like instructed on the Nokogiri-Website. Since then, everything is working fine, on Mac 10.6.8 as well as 10.7.2.